# JMeter execute ant test local failed

Tags: ant, jmeter

I'm following JMeter wiki page of [CommittingChanges](https://wiki.apache.org/jmeter/CommittingChanges?action=diff&rev1=4&rev2=5) which was updated.

I'm running

> - ant checkstyle
> - ant package
> - ant test

Test Failed with error in differences from Bug52310.csv:

```
BUILD FAILED
C:\jmeter\jmeter\build.xml:2681: The following error occurred while executing th
is line:
C:\jmeter\jmeter\build.xml:2621: CSV Files are not identical.
        C:\jmeter\jmeter\bin\testfiles\Bug52310.csv
        ComputeIPAddr,200,OK,TG2 1-1,text,true
HTTP-Request-HC31,200,OK,TG2 1-1,text,true
HTTP-Request-HC4,200,OK,TG2 1-1,text,true

        C:\jmeter\jmeter\bin\Bug52310.csv
        ComputeIPAddr,200,OK,TG2 1-1,text,true
HTTP-Request-HC31,Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP resp
onse message: Network is unreachable: connect,TG2 1-1,text,false
HTTP-Request-HC4,Non HTTP response code: java.net.SocketException,Non HTTP respo
nse message: Network is unreachable: connect,TG2 1-1,text,false

Total time: 3 minutes 9 seconds
```

Is it a bug or configuration/network issue? can all JMeter tests be execute in local environment?

**EDIT**

Also next step is to run different test

> ant test-headless or ant test-headed (whichever was not run by the ant test)

Why not execute `ant test-both` in the first place?

when I execute `ant test-headed` and even `and test-both` it worked successfully

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding your first issue, it looks like a temporary connectivity issue from your machine or more probably that test computes an IP address for your machine that is not reachable .

This test exists to test ip-spoofing feature by setting the ip source to your machine address.

Run it in gui and see what IP is computed on your machine then try to resolve it.

Regarding ant test-both, yes it would be better, report a bug please.